# Underbrace outside parentheses

Tags: math-mode, equations, alignat, underbrace

How do I move the underbrace out of the big parentheses while still keeping it underneath the term?

[image]

```
\begin{alignat*}{4}
& \frac{E_{0-0}}{hc} &&= C+\frac{E'(\upsilon'=0)}{hc} &\\
&                    &&= C+\frac{1}{hc}\left(\hbar\omega'_e\left(0+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\underbrace{\hbar\chi'\omega'_e\left(0+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}_{\approx0}\right) &  \quad\Big|\quad\parbox{9em}{\small{Vernachlässigung\\der Anharmonizität}}\\
&                    &&\approx C+\frac{\omega'_e}{4\pi c}
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: Use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` instead of `\left(` and `\right)` for the too big ones.

Comment: And why `alignat` when `align` would do?

Comment: Hi, just a general comment regarding your questions: If you have gotten one or more helpful answers, consider accepting an answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Also consider upvoting any useful answers you got, by clicking the up-pointing arrow next to the answer. (See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I replaced `alignat*` with just `align*` as others also said and `\Bigl,\Bigr` are also better. The `\frac{1}{2}` looks unnecessarily big, so I used `\tfrac`. Finally, to lower the `underbrace` you can add a virtual rule like `\vphantom{\rule[-1em]{0pt}{0pt}}` noting that a `\smash` is required to keep line spacing consistent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \frac{E_{0-0}}{hc} &= C+\frac{E'(\upsilon'=0)}{hc} &\\
                    &= C+\frac{1}{hc}\Bigl(\hbar\omega'_e\left(0+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)-\smash{\underbrace{\vphantom{\rule[-1em]{0pt}{0pt}}\hbar\chi'\omega'_e\left(0+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}_{\approx0}}\Bigr) &  \quad\Big|\quad\parbox{9em}{\small{Vernachlässigung\\der Anharmonizität}}\\
                    &\approx C+\frac{\omega'_e}{4\pi c}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several aspects where this display can be improved.

The main one is avoiding `\left` and `\right` for those big parentheses. However there are more.

1. `alignat` is the wrong tool here, `align` is simpler and better
2. the `\underbrace` construction should be surrounded by braces, for avoiding issues with possible thin spaces inserted
3. you don't need to guess the width for the text, using a `tabular` is simpler, with the advantage that the vertical bar will be automatically adjusted
4. the exponent to the right parenthesis should be moved nearer to it
5. a thin space should be added after the underbraced part, so the brace will not clash with the parenthesis
6. since the underbrace ends up over nothing, we can `\smash` it

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{E_{0-0}}{hc}
  &= C+\frac{E'(\upsilon'=0)}{hc} \\
  &= C+\frac{1}{hc}\biggl(
      \hbar\omega'_e\left(0+\frac{1}{2}\right)-
      \smash{\underbrace{\hbar\chi'\omega'_e\left(0+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\!2}}_{\approx0}}
     \,\biggr)
     &&\mbox{\small
       \begin{tabular}{|l@{}}
       Vernachlässigung\\
       der Anharmonizität
       \end{tabular}%
     }\\
  &\approx C+\frac{\omega'_e}{4\pi c}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
 \frac{E_{0-0}}{hc} &= C+\frac{E'(\upsilon'=0)}{hc} \\
                    &= C+\frac{1}{hc}\biggl(\hbar\omega'_e\Bigl(0+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)-\underbrace{\hbar\chi'\omega'_e\Bigl(0+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{\!2}}_{\approx0}\,\biggr)
                    &  \quad\Big|\text{\small\begin{tabular}{l@{}}Vernachlässigung\\der Anharmonizität\end{tabular}}\\
                    &\approx C+\frac{\omega'_e}{4\pi c}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 0):

To move it outside the right parenthesis, don't use the `\left … \right` pair and replace it with `\biggl … \biggr`. You'll have better sized parentheses and a better horizontal spacing.

In addition, note that with  the `alignat` environment,  the number of ampersands for `n`  alignment groups is `2n-1`: the first `&` is for the 1st alignment point, the 2nd introduces the second group, the 3rd `&` is for the alignment point of the second group, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \frac{E_{0-0}}{hc} & = C+\frac{E'(\upsilon'=0)}{hc}\\
    & = C+\frac{1}{hc}\biggl(\hbar\omega'_e\Bigl(0+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)-\underbrace{\hbar\chi'\omega'_e\Bigl(0+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)²\biggr) \!\! }_{\approx0} & & \quad\Big|\quad\parbox{9em}{\small{Vernachlässigung \\der Anharmonizität}}\\
  &\approx C+\frac{\omega'_e}{4πc}
\end{alignat*}
```

\end{document} 
[image]

Comment: You got the order of the parenthesis and the underbrace wrong.

Comment: @yo': That's what the O.P. asked for.